# DataTable not Rendering corrrectly after xmlhttp.responseText

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

`DataTable` is showing but only after I change number of items per page. Similarly, pagination is only working if I search an item.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var col = [{
            "mData": "row1"
        }, {
            "mData": "row2"
        }, {
            "bSortable": false,
            "mData": null,
            "sTitle": "Actions",
            "bSearchable": false,
            "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
                return '<a href="' + full.link + '"><img alt="Download" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Ppbc_icon_download.png" title="Download"/></a>';
            }
        }];
        var ss = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        $('#myTable').dataTable({
            "aaData": ss,
            "aoColumns": col,
            "bDestroy": true
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: No question is a bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `aoColumns`, used `columns`.

```
var col = [{
    "mData": "row1",
    "sTitle": "row1"
}, // <-- which values to use inside object
{
    "mData": "row2",
    "sTitle": "row2"
}, {
    "bSortable": false,
    "mData": null,
    "sTitle": "Download",
    "bSearchable": false,
    "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
        return '<a href="' + full.Link + '"><img alt="Download" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Ppbc_icon_download.png" title="Download"/></a>';
    }
}];


JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
var ss = $('#myTable').dataTable({
    "aaData": ss,
    "columns": col,
    "bDestroy": true
});
}
};
```